# Find Rangy marker ID

Tags: javascript, object, selection, multidimensional-array, rangy

I'm attempting to find the markerId value of a saved rangy selection.

I've tried the following:

```
marker = savedSel.rangeInfos;
console.log(marker.markerId);
```

But it returns "undefined".
Outputting the marker variable directly returns an object that clearly has "markerId" as an item.  I just seem to be having trouble getting to that third dimension in the multidimensional object.

How could this be done?

Comment: Can you show us what output you're seeing when you examine that object?

Answer (score 0):

`rangeInfos` is an array because a selection can have multiple ranges in Firefox. If you've saved a collapsed selection (i.e. there is no selection, just a caret) then you can get the marker ID from the first and only member of `rangeInfos`:

```
var savedSel = rangy.saveSelection();
console.log(savedSel.rangeInfos[0].markerId);
```